# Mouse unusable in Java programs under Gnome Shell

Tags: x11, java, mouse

I am trying to use Oracle SQLDeveloper (`sqldeveloper-4.1.2.20.64-no-jre.zip`) under Gnome Shell (Fedora 23).

The issue is that the mouse is completely unusable in that application.

As-is, button clicks are not registered and text in the editor is selected on mouse over.

Setting the environment variable

```
DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome-shell
```

fixes the strange selection behavior but still no left-button clicks are registered. Right mouse-button clicks are registered, though.

I am using the Java from the Fedora Repository:

```
$ java -version 
openjdk version "1.8.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Keyboard shortcuts do work as expected.

Thus, my question: how to make the mouse work again inside Java programs under Gnome Shell/Fedora 23?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last Fedora 23 updates seem to include a fix.

Now the mouse works again as expected in Java programs.

Even with the default `DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome` environment variable setting.

(With sqldeveloper-4.1.2.20 you also does not have to unset the 
`GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` environment variable anymore - was necessary in previous versions.)

I suspect that the fix was in a gnome/xorg related package, e.g. `gnome-session-*`. Java (openjdk) itself certainly was not updated.